# What can _time suffix use for laravel database design?

Tags: laravel, database-design, naming

Most of us are used to the field names like `create_time`, `update_time`. Now laravel changed that into `created_at`, `updated_at`. Therefore the `_time` suffix are available for other things.

I, am self, take naming very seriously. And I don't want to waste any good word for naming. What can _time suffix use for laravel database design?

Answer (score 0):

you can override the default laravel created_at and updated_at fields.

```php
class MyModel extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'create_time';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'update_time';
}
```

and also when creating the database instead of using laravel default `$table->timestamps();` you can specify the names of the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns names as your wish.

```php
 $table->timestamp('create_time');
 $table->timestamp('update_time');
```